# SASS: Include certain constants in various files

Tags: sass

This is the *style.sass*:

```
@import 'constants_style'

#modal 
    color: $style_color
```

This is *_constants_style.scss*:

```
$style_color: #ffffff;
```

I can create a *style.css* file by typing:

```
sass style.sass style.css
```

Here's the problem: Is there a way to create two `.css` files (`style.css` and `style2.css`) by using the same `style.sass` and, possibly, two constants (`_constants_style.scss` and `_constants_style2.scss`) using command line?

Sorry if it gets hard to understand, but the final look would be:

*_constants_style.scss*:

```
$style_color: #ffffff;
```

*_constants_style2.scss*:

```
$style_color: #000000;
```

*style.sass*:

```
@import 'one of _contstants'

#modal 
    color: $style_color
```

So in the end I would have two .css files:

*style.css*

```
#modal {
    color: $ffffff
}
```

and *style2.css*:

```
#modal {
    color: $000000
}
```